# Descobrir ação ao clicar no Certificado para fazer chamada por curl

Tags: php, javascript

No site https://satsp.fazenda.sp.gov.br/COMSAT/Account/LoginSSL.aspx, depois de escolher o radio Contribuinte, preciso saber qual ação é feita para fazer a mesma chamada pelo PHP via curl.

Olhei no javascript mas não consegui identificar.

Como posso fazer a mesma chamada via curl no PHP?

Obrigado!